# Django. Как связать модели друг с другом?

Tags: html, python, алгоритм, django

Как ссылаясь на описание статьи, сделать краткое описание этой-же статьи в новостной ленте? И можно обойтись одним приложением?

Если будут вопросы или нужно будет больше инфы - пишите! Готов связаться через что-угодно при необходимости.

```
from django.db import models

class news(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок',max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField('Изображение',upload_to='news/')
    text = models.TextField('Описание')
    сomment = models.TextField('Комментарий', max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class news_line(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок',max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField('Изображение',upload_to='news_line/')
    text = models.TextField('Краткое описание')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата и время')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: А зачем? Статью и её краткое описание можно хранить в одной модели, и никто не запрещает использовать одно приложение

Comment: Да, если у вас к одной статье будет идти лишь одно краткое описание, то просто засуньте это описание в ваш класс `news`. Например: `short_text = models.TextField('Краткое описание')`

Comment: Спасибо, я понял)